# How to solve "cannot identify image file" in Keras

Tags: python, image, keras, python-imaging-library, conv-neural-network

I am trying to input my train images with float32 data type and PNG format using `from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator`, but I receive error `UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x000001E5AD9BEB48>`.

This is the code I am using:

```
batch_size = 16
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()


img_train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
                "train/image/",
                target_size=(16,16),
                batch_size=batch_size,
                class_mode= None,
                color_mode='rgba',
                shuffle=False)
                
    
label_train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
                "train/label/",
                target_size=(16,16),
                batch_size=batch_size,
                class_mode=None,
                shuffle=False,
                color_mode='grayscale')

train_generator = zip(img_train_generator, label_train_generator)
```

result:

```
Found 1524 images belonging to 1 classes.
Found 1524 images belonging to 1 classes.
```

The error log appears after running the following code:

```
X_train, y_train=next(train_generator)
X_train.shape, y_train.shape
```

Can anyone help to solve this error?

-----error log:

---

```
UnidentifiedImageError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-029022e123bf> in <module>
     25 train_generator = zip(img_train_generator, label_train_generator)
     26 
---> 27 X_train, y_train=next(train_generator)
     28 X_train.shape, y_train.shape

~\.conda\envs\myenv-36\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\iterator.py in __next__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    102 
    103     def __next__(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 104         return self.next(*args, **kwargs)
    105 
    106     def next(self):

~\.conda\envs\myenv-36\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\iterator.py in next(self)
    114         # The transformation of images is not under thread lock
    115         # so it can be done in parallel
--> 116         return self._get_batches_of_transformed_samples(index_array)
    117 
    118     def _get_batches_of_transformed_samples(self, index_array):

~\.conda\envs\myenv-36\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\iterator.py in _get_batches_of_transformed_samples(self, index_array)
    228                            color_mode=self.color_mode,
    229                            target_size=self.target_size,
--> 230                            interpolation=self.interpolation)
    231             x = img_to_array(img, data_format=self.data_format)
    232             # Pillow images should be closed after `load_img`,

~\.conda\envs\myenv-36\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\utils.py in load_img(path, grayscale, color_mode, target_size, interpolation)
    112                           'The use of `load_img` requires PIL.')
    113     with open(path, 'rb') as f:
--> 114         img = pil_image.open(io.BytesIO(f.read()))
    115         if color_mode == 'grayscale':
    116             # if image is not already an 8-bit, 16-bit or 32-bit grayscale image

~\.conda\envs\myenv-36\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py in open(fp, mode, formats)
   2957         warnings.warn(message)
   2958     raise UnidentifiedImageError(
-> 2959         "cannot identify image file %r" % (filename if filename else fp)
   2960     )
   2961
```

Comment: Are you certain there are only image files in the "train/image/" directory?

Comment: @ Dr. Casual, yes. There are only images in the folders. I updated the question. Please see the result.

Comment: It's possible the image file is corrupt. Have you isolated which file it is?

Comment: @ Hugo, only when I convert the float32 image to 8bit, I can use `X_train, y_train=next(train_generator)
X_train.shape, y_train.shape`. But the data range for final prediction images is between 0-255. I used the code from [https://opensource.com/article/17/2/python-tricks-artists] and it shows in any cases (float32 or 8bit), the images are corrupted. But still I can get the final prediction using 8bit input images. Is there any other way to check if the images are corrupted?or any solution to read float32 images?